# Is there a way to send HTML formatted emails with WordPress' wp_mail() function?

Tags: hooks, wp-mail, html-email

Is there an action_hook or something similar that could help me achieve this?

I tried adding markup in a PHP string variable and just fired off an email with the `wp_mail()` function like so:

```
$email_to = 'someaddress@gmail.com';
$email_subject = 'Email subject';
$email_body = "<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>";
$send_mail = wp_mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_body);
```

But it showed up as plain text?

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this amazing article on wp_mail() https://www.phparticles.com/wordpress/how-to-use-wp-mail-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

from [wp_mail codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail):

> The default content type is 'text/plain' which does not allow using HTML. However, you can set the content type of the email by using the 'wp_mail_content_type' filter.

```
// In theme's functions.php or plug-in code:

function wpse27856_set_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
```

Comment: Hmm sounds useful. Just a question, any particular reason why you named your function wpse27856_set_content_type?

Comment: No, it's just a unique name based on the id of this particular question. wpse = wp stachexchange, 27856 is the id of this question in the URL. I just do that to avoid potential collisions if people copy/paste code out of here.

Comment: You can also just include the Content-Type in your email headers. Check out how the Notifly plugin does it.

Comment: oh yeah, ha ha. What a n00b I am. Guess it is the id of this post.

Comment: Should the email be a .txt file or a .html file? I'm using this method but if I view source it is a .txt file and the embedded image is not processed.

Comment: @AlxVallejo if your sending from file you will probably need to read the file as a string first.

Comment: passing the headers in is a more efficient method than adding a hook. -1

Comment: @Jeremy sure, but passing the headers directly is not an option in many cases, like when it's not your code calling `wp_mail`.

Comment: @Milo You are correct but for this question the headers are the correct answer.

Comment: This will break your password reset email, because the reset link is wrapped in <>.

Comment: Doesn't this break any other code that expects `wp_mail` to send plain text email, rather than HTML email?

Comment: @SimonJosefKok, if I'm reading this bug report correctly, the issue of breaking password reset emails is resolved as of WordPress 5.4. Sounds like they decided to remove the angle brackets from the email address. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578#comment:24

Answer (score 172):

As an alternative, you can specify the Content-Type HTTP header in the $headers parameter:

```
$to = 'sendto@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Comment: This works better as the add_filter sometimes shows as attachment. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is the generally best way to-do this. The top answer will interfere with other plugins and cause problems.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This answer should be the accepted!

Comment: It appears to my reading of the wp_mail() source that the headers cannot be an array, but needs to be in the form of 'to: joe@domain.com'. Still trying to test this, and I'll bow to more experienced developers to check my accuracy.

Comment: This is far superior as it's way too easy with the `add_filter()` technique to forget your `remove_filter('wp_mail_content_type');` and then leave things in a mess for other plugins.

Answer (score 14):

Don't forget to remove the content type filter after you use the wp_mail function.
Following the accepted answer naming you should do this after wp_mail is executed:

```
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
```

Check this ticket here - Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, no?

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way I'm going to share below. Even you can style your mail body as your wish. Maybe it's helpful for you.

```
$email_to = 'someaddress@gmail.com';
$email_subject = 'Email subject';

// <<<EOD it is PHP heredoc syntax
$email_body = <<<EOD
This is your new <b style="color: red; font-style: italic;">password</b> : {$password}
EOD;

$headers = ['Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'];

$send_mail = wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers );
```

More about PHP heredoc syntax https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

Use `ob_start`, because this will allow you to use WP variables/functions like bloginfo etc.

make a PHP file and paste your HTML in that file(use wp variables inside that php file if needed).

Use the below code:

```
 $to = 'Email Address';
 $subject = 'Your Subject';

 ob_start();
 include(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/email-template.php');//Template File Path
 $body = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();

 $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: Test <test@test.com>');
 wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

this will keep your code clean and due to ob_start we will also save the time of loading the file.