# How can I send an email in my plugin?

Tags: 404-error, email

I'm making a plugin that emails the site webmaster when I go to the 404 page.  The script checks if the referring link is on our site, and then sends an email to the webmaster.

```
$message = "
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alton Bible Church - Broken Link</title>
            <style type=\"text/css\">
                * {
                    font-family:Arial;
                }
                table {
                    background:#eee;
                    padding:15px;
                }
                #table {
                    width:500px;
                    overflow:scroll;
                }
                td {
                    border: 1px solid #aaa;
                    padding:10px;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>There's a broken link on My Website</p>
        <div id=\"table\">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Broken Link</td><td>Referring Link</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href=\"" . $broken . "\">" . $broken . "</a></td><td><a href=\"" . $referrer . "\">" . $referrer . "</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: My Website <no-reply@mysite.net>' . '\r\n';
mail("Webmaster <webmaster@mysite.net>", "My Website - Broken Link", $message, $headers);
```

The problem is, the email is not being sent.  Does WordPress not allow me to use mail()?

The problem shouldn't be with the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wp_mail()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45289/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-wp-mail/45291#45291), not just `mail()`. It is a wrapper for [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), a class that takes care for many problems the native `mail()` function often gets.

See my plugin [404 Tools](https://github.com/toscho/T5-404-Tools) for how to use it in this case. To send an HTML email see [Milo’s answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27858/73) to a related question.

Comment: It still doesn't send the email.

Comment: Update the code in your question, enable the [debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), and add all errors you get to the question too.

Comment: Test my plugin. If it works there is a glitch your PHP code.

Comment: Still nothing.  (I am using XAMPP right now to develop.)

Comment: You have to [set up Mercury in XAMPP](http://www.danieltmurphy.com/setting-up-mercury-smtp/). Or test it on a real Linux server.

Comment: Is this available for Mac?  On one of my macs, the mail() works fine (I didn't have to set up anything).  On the one I'm using, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress doesn't block the php `mail()` function. One error that i can see is that `'\r\n'` should be in double quotes like this `"\r\n"`

Even though `mail()` works, it's a good practice to use wordpress functions, here `wp_mail()`

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your functions.php and it should be OK.

```
//SENDS 404 EMAIL TO ADMIN
function email_admin($location){
    $blname=get_option('blogname');
    $admemail = get_option('admin_email');
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $checkip = "http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_".$ipaddress;
    $mailhead  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mailhead .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $mailhead .= 'From: "' . $blname . '" \r\n";
    $mailsubj= $blname.': 404 error';
    $mailbody='Someone wanted to go to '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$location." but you haven't created this page yet. Maybe you can have a look and see if anything needs to be fixed.\r\n
Their IP address is: ".$ipaddress."\r\n\nIn case you want to check if these are THE BAD GUYS, you can do it at $checkip";

    @mail($admemail,$mailsubj,$mailbody,$mailhead);
}

function mail_me_errors(){
    global $wp_query;
    $location=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($wp_query->is_404){
        email_admin($location);
    }
}
add_action('get_header', 'mail_me_errors');
```

Comment: Please add more explanation than just "put this in your functions.php". An answer should cover the "why" as well.